# Passing in user inputs with mpirun

Tags: python, parallel-computing, hpc, mpi

I am building a quantum circuit simulator using mpi4py. The simulator takes user inputs to build the initial system and quantum gates the system passes through. I can get the code to work if I do not use user inputs and just hard code in the system and gates. However, I cannot figure out how to get the code to work when I do use user inputs. If I mpirun the code with the user inputs it does not allow me to enter inputs and then the code gives an error because variables are never defined. I tried to get the user inputs and then mpirun the rest of the code but it does not recognize the variables obtained from user inputs. I tried to pass in the user input variables into my code I am mpirunning, but I also could not get this to work. I am not sure how to deal with this issue!

Comment: When you say "user input", do you mean "stuff your program reads from the console"? "User input" could of course also be "stuff read from a parameter file"...

Comment: Stuff your program reads from the console. Like I run the code and it says how many qubits do you want in your system and I input the number of qubits I want in my system.

Comment: This seems more a programming than a computational science question.

Answer (score 1):

Input from the console may work on process zero, if that runs locally, but will certainly not work on other ranks. However, I wouldn't even do interactive input on process zero.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $PMI_RANK -eq 0 ] ; then 
  ( echo 5 ; echo 1 ; echo foo ) | $*
else
  exec $*
fi
```

Put that in a script and  start that with mpirun:

```
mpirun myscript.sh myprogram
```

The environment variable for the MPI rank may have a different name in your MPI.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am not sure what this does. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: Instead of running your program you run a shell script that calls your program. Then you let the shell script provide input to the program.

Answer (score 1):

MPI is designed so that the same executable is started on a number of machines, none of which may be the one on which the `mpirun` program is called. Furthermore, MPI jobs are typically put into a queue, and the actual job may run hours or days later.

As a consequence, MPI jobs are not meant to be used in an interactive mode, but all input should be provided in a way so that the program -- wherever and whenever it is actually running -- can access it in a non-interactive way.

Comment: So if I wanted to build a quantum circuit simulator in a parallel environment I would have to hard code in the system and gates I want and then run that way instead of it be an interactive experience? That makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Comment: @Orphea12 Or ask users to write their commands into an input file that the program reads at run-time.  That's what most MPI programs do: Read their inputs from either an input file or from the command line.